# UDF function throws null pointer exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following method:

```
 class LoadService(configs: Configs, siteDataFrame:DataFrame) extends Serializable{
var serviceConfig =configs.getServiceConfig
         def insertIntoCassandra(siteMetaData: MetaData, dataFrame: DataFrame): Unit ={
            var query = cassandraUtil.buildInsertQuery(activeReplicaKeySpace, tableName, columns, sparkTempTable)
            cassandraSQLContext.sql(query)
            logger.info("Query executed")
          }
         def getSiteId: Int = {
            System.out.println("test: " + serviceConfig.getAdminKeyspace)
            return serviceConfig.getSiteId.toInt
          }
          cassandraSQLContext.udf.register("getSiteId", getSiteId _)
    }
```

So another class calls insertIntoCassandra and then var query has getSiteId(). So it triggers the getSiteId UDF function but for some reason, the UDF function always has null pointer exception. If I place serviceConfig.getSiteId.toInt inside insertIntoCassandra function, that function has access to serviceConfig but for some reason, all the UDF functions I have seem to throw null pointer exception

serviceConfig is defined as a variable in the class.
Anytime this function is called, it throws null pointer exception at serviceConfig.getAdminKeySpace. Seems like serviceConfig is null. But if I place the same statement, outside the UDF function anywhere else in the class, it seems to work. And the UDF function is being called AFTER this class is instantiated too. Does the UDF function have not access to serviceConfig or something? The class which contains this method extends Serializable so im not sure if that would make a difference.

Comment: Can you tell how you are defining variable `serviceConfig` ?

Comment: It does seem like a scope issue. Can you post more of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Actually so the problem turned out to be this statement:

```
var serviceConfig =configs.getServiceConfig
```

Configs is another java class that had the Configuration java object and Configuration is NOT serializable so it wont work with spark cause spark requires serializability.